# Sorting socketing queries with IF statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

(ws for node.js)

Like this;

```js
socketserver.on('connection', function(socket) {

 socket.on('message', function(data) {
      
      // This is in eventone.html on /eventone
      if(data == 'eventone') {
  console.log("Event one triggered!");
                socket.send(foo);
  socket.close();
      }
      
      // This is in eventtwo.html on /eventtwo
      if(data == 'eventtwo') {
  console.log("Event two triggered!");
                socket.send(bar);
  socket.close();
      }
      
      // This is in eventthree.html on /eventthree
      if(data == 'eventthree') {
  console.log("Event three triggered!");
                socket.send(foobar);
  socket.close();
      }
      
 });

});
```

Is this a good idea for socketing data through one socketserver across different pages?

I want 'foo' to get sent to eventone.html, 'bar' to eventtwo.html and 'foobar' to eventthree.html, which are loaded on the client side, whenever the client sends the respective event through a button press (or whatever).

If this is a good idea, why would you ever use static routing and such things with request and response, why not just send everything through a socket?

Comment: why do you close the socket after one message? also, it would be nice to setup your routes declarative instead of top-town procedural, something like an object of paths that could be iterated, tested, modified/patched/upgraded/extended  in-place, etc... anytime you see a bunch of `if(`s, there's usually a better more manageable way of implementing the forking logic.

Comment: It's a testing carryover. Doesn't that mean it would be synchronous? You can't have two functions access an object at the same time, so they're queued, breaking synchronicity.  Regardless, is this -kind- of request-matching how everyone usually does it, in or out of an object of paths, or is there a crucial component of socketing that I'm missing?

Comment: you can't have two anythings access the same object at once in JS, it's single threaded, so there's no such thing as a tie. most folks use a route object or map, afaik. most router provide methods to add and remove paths during run-time, whereas changing an `if` statement will usually require a reload.

Comment: in terms of "why not just send everything through a socket": there's many advantages to http over sockets, chiefly a familier req/res interaction pattern instead of a a flood of messages from everyone hitting the same variables. also there's logging, cookies, auth, playing well with existing infrastructure, caching, error codes, redirects, timeouts, and more that http has going for it.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's apt to use my normal routing for express, app.get('/whatever', function(req,res) {}); route it normally, and then put my socket event reader inside of the route itself, instead of trying to manage it all in if statements. Then when a user is on the '/whatever' page, he can call a request that needs to be updated in real time, and the socket will take care of it. That's a better way, correct?

Comment: use http to serve content urls, sockets to serve content updates.